# Value Assignment by specific indices error in Tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, numpy-slicing

I'm trying to build a custom loss function for my model, but whenever I try to convert Tensors into .numpy() arrays with run_eagerly = True, it gives "WARNING: Gradients do not exist for variables ...". So I debugged other custom loss functions implemented using TensorFlow. But in my case, I need to apply to mask and splitting index arrays and then use those arrays as indices to apply some sort of arithmetic functions using broadcasting. But I retrieved indices lists after masking, but I just have to access those indices and add specific functions. But I found no way in TensorFlow to implement that in a vectorized way.

```
error = y_true - y_false
print(y_true.shape, y_pred.shape)
print(error.shape)
print("Error values: ", error)
```

> Output: (10, 1000), (10, 1000)

---

> (10, 1000)

---

> Error values: <tf.Tensor: shape=(10, 1000), dtype=float64, numpy=
> array([[-10, 0, 8, ..., 3,
> -1.5,  -2.5],
> ...,
> [ 2.5,  8 ,  6.5, ..., 5.5,
> 3.5, -0.5]])>

```
mask = tf.where(y_true > 5)
i = mask[0]
j = mask[1]
print(i[:5])
print(j[:5])
```

Results:

> (<tf.Tensor: shape=(5,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64)>,

---

> <tf.Tensor: shape=(5,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([19, 26, 28, 35, 39], dtype=int64)>)

In NumPy, I can access it using:

```
error[i, j] = error[i, j] * 5
```

**What I want is to replace with new values of error in a specified position after executing the above code and get values like:**

> Error values: <tf.Tensor: shape=(10, 1000), dtype=float64, numpy= array([[-10, 0, 16*, ..., 3,
> -1.5,  -2.5],
> ...,
> [ 2.5,  16* ,  13*, ..., 11*,
> 3.5, -0.5]])>

### But when I try to execute this as Tensors, it gives the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [193], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 error[i, j]

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py:153, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    151 except Exception as e:
    152   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
--> 153   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    154 finally:
    155   del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py:899, in _check_index(idx)
    894 dtype = getattr(idx, "dtype", None)
    895 if (dtype is None or dtypes.as_dtype(dtype) not in _SUPPORTED_SLICE_DTYPES or
    896     idx.shape and len(idx.shape) == 1):
    897   # TODO(slebedev): IndexError seems more appropriate here, but it
    898   # will break `_slice_helper` contract.
--> 899   raise TypeError(_SLICE_TYPE_ERROR + ", got {!r}".format(idx))

TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got <tf.Tensor: shape=(4797,), dtype=int64, numpy=array([ 0,  0,  0, ..., 26, 26, 26], dtype=int64)>
```

I tried using other functions provided by TensorFlow too, but those did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your comment correctly, the following code should be appropriate. It multiplies by alpha (=2. here) all error values greater than 5

```
# generate some error tensor
error = tf.random.uniform(shape=(10, 3), minval=0, maxval=10, dtype=tf.float64)
print('input error')
print(error)
float_mask = tf.cast(error>5, dtype=tf.float64)
print('mask')
print(float_mask)
alpha = 2.
print('gain = %f' % alpha)
error = error + (alpha-1.)*float_mask*error
print('output error')
print(error)
```

which gives:

input error

```
tf.Tensor( [[9.47020833 6.21211945 2.56257082]  [8.2855179
6.23372048 9.39559957]  [5.2926297  2.62602144 4.44665184]  [6.49200992 7.09389259 1.04311547]  [9.39402112 2.68713794 7.71738653] [6.4853496  2.99997236 9.88983946]  [3.57130888 5.73827016 5.91022104] [2.58102132 4.01791191 3.19829238]  [9.28263857 4.73230455 6.24950981] [0.38713425 3.56589859 8.74955686]], shape=(10, 3), dtype=float64)
```

mask

```
tf.Tensor( [[1. 1. 0.]  [1. 1. 1.]  [1. 0. 0.]  [1. 1. 0.]  [1.
0. 1.]  [1. 0. 1.]  [0. 1. 1.]  [0. 0. 0.]  [1. 0. 1.]  [0. 0. 1.]], shape=(10, 3), dtype=float64)
```

gain

```
gain = 2.000000
```

output error

```
tf.Tensor( [[18.94041665 12.42423889  2.56257082]  [16.5710358  12.46744096
18.79119913]  [10.58525941  2.62602144  4.44665184]  [12.98401983 14.18778517  1.04311547]  [18.78804224  2.68713794 15.43477305]  [12.9706992   2.99997236 19.77967893]  [ 3.57130888 11.47654031
11.82044208]  [ 2.58102132  4.01791191  3.19829238]  [18.56527714  4.73230455 12.49901962]  [ 0.38713425  3.56589859 17.49911371]], shape=(10, 3), dtype=float64)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @elbe, it works. I would like to get suggestions in case I want to replace the multiplication of error by alpha with the power of error? (I.e. Instead of multiplying it with any value, if I want to take its square?

Comment: You use the following formula :  `error = (1-float_mask)  * error + float_mask * tf.math.square(error)`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use indices assignement in tensorflow, but this can be overcome using [tf.gather_nd](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) and [tf.scatter_nd](https://tensorflow.google.cn/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd).
Here is an example with dummy input data

```
y_true = tf.random.uniform(shape=(10, 6), minval=0, maxval=10, dtype=tf.int32)
mask = tf.where(y_true > 5)
y_mask = tf.scatter_nd(mask, tf.gather_nd(y_true, mask), shape=tf.cast(tf.shape(y_true), tf.int64))
print(y_true)
print(y_mask)
print(y_mask*4+y_true)
```

outputs
y_true:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[9 9 0 1 4 2]
 [9 8 6 3 9 8]
 [9 0 1 4 7 7]
 [4 8 6 3 4 1]
 [9 1 8 9 3 9]
 [2 8 3 4 9 2]
 [2 5 7 5 2 2]
 [6 7 6 7 9 4]
 [2 8 9 5 2 1]
 [7 4 1 9 7 9]], shape=(10, 6), dtype=int32)
```

y_mask:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[9 9 0 0 0 0]
 [9 8 6 0 9 8]
 [9 0 0 0 7 7]
 [0 8 6 0 0 0]
 [9 0 8 9 0 9]
 [0 8 0 0 9 0]
 [0 0 7 0 0 0]
 [6 7 6 7 9 0]
 [0 8 9 0 0 0]
 [7 0 0 9 7 9]], shape=(10, 6), dtype=int32)
```

y_mask*4+y_true:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[45 45  0  1  4  2]
 [45 40 30  3 45 40]
 [45  0  1  4 35 35]
 [ 4 40 30  3  4  1]
 [45  1 40 45  3 45]
 [ 2 40  3  4 45  2]
 [ 2  5 35  5  2  2]
 [30 35 30 35 45  4]
 [ 2 40 45  5  2  1]
 [35  4  1 45 35 45]], shape=(10, 6), dtype=int32)
```

Another solution is to use directly the mask and cast it to int32 or float32 (or other):

```
mask_float = tf.cast(y_true>5, tf.int32)
print(mask_float*y_true)
```

y_mask v2:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[9 9 0 0 0 0]
 [9 8 6 0 9 8]
 [9 0 0 0 7 7]
 [0 8 6 0 0 0]
 [9 0 8 9 0 9]
 [0 8 0 0 9 0]
 [0 0 7 0 0 0]
 [6 7 6 7 9 0]
 [0 8 9 0 0 0]
 [7 0 0 9 7 9]], shape=(10, 6), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Hi @elbe, it's not exactly what I asked, just a little relevant. I have edited my question to clarify things even better. I'm working with float data type Tensors. Also, as you did, there are zeros replaced with values where mask criteria could not satisfied. But I need to replace new updated values on the same positions where mask criteria is fulfilled. Please help me, thanks.